# Accused of cheating by proctor due to information on scrap sheet

Tags: university, cheating

Sorry if this is a bit long. I took a final for an intro elective (I'm a college senior), a pretty easy A- GPA booster class (average before this final was 90+).

I have learning disorders so I get to take the exam in a private room. Shortly into the exam, I asked to take a bathroom break and grabbed tissue from the washroom. Then I went back into the exam room and continued, got carried away and started doodling on one of the tissue papers. I believe I wrote about three words on the sheet before the proctor came by and asked why I had unauthorized "notes". I explained that these weren't notes and just me doodling. He asked why I didn't doodle on my scrap and I said I was using my one scrap sheet for actual calculations and didn't want to run out of space on it. He said ok but that we would need to go to the head proctor and report it just in case, and if she was fine with it I could keep writing. He gave me back the papers and we got up to head out to her office.

Once out of the exam rooms, he said on a second thought to give him the papers instead and he wanted to hand them to her. I said no, sorry, I can't do that, we are already heading there, whats the big deal with me holding them? He said something about protocol, but I told him I didn't feel comfortable with handing him my papers.

He then tried to grab them from me, which was when I ran into the bathroom because I felt like he was trying to attack me (been raped before - guess I got triggered). He goes into the bathroom with me still trying to grab my papers. I ran out telling him to get another proctor because I am feeling harassed and uncomfortable, so I went into the next washroom and he followed me in there. I had a panic attack, and ran out again trying to get as far away from him as possible, that was when he called a female proctor who sat with me the entire time in the hallways till they brought a counselor. Now he claims that I cheated with unauthorized notes and I have to go to a meeting with the dean.

Also they are bringing as evidence my scrap sheet because I had previously been given the same exam but couldn't complete it due to being sick (I memorized a keyword from each question wanting to see (also kind of hoping)  if they would administer the exact same exam and matched the old questions to the new ones). I don't see how that has anything to do with the three words I wrote on the other sheet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Basically how do I prove that I did in fact memorize the questions? They sent me my scrap sheet where i matched version 1 to version 2 so even if I match it again they'll say that I already saw it from the evidence file and memorized it then.

Comment: If I were the Dean, I would ask you this question: "Why did you grab tissue from the washroom?".

Comment: I had a runny nose, and they saw me with the tissue.

Comment: If you memorized the questions, just write them down or match them again in the presence of the dean, should be the fastest way to prove that.

Comment: Are there any witnesses to the part where he tried to grab your sheets and you ran away? Someone who could testify if the proctor's behavior was out of line?

Comment: Matching them again wont work because they already gave me my scrap as evidence and will say that I looked at that.

Comment: There should be witnesses to the fact that he followed me into the washroom on two different occasions and that I had a panic attack because of his behaviour.

Comment: I think one important question is the story he is telling. Is he openly lying about his actions or what happened, or does he just have a different interpretation of things than you do?

Comment: I have no idea what story he is telling. But I also dont know what he cold be telling that would justify following me in the washroom, there were two other proctors that happened to be absent the whole time till I ran out of the washroom trying to get away from him. But they had to get a counsellor because I had a major panic attack - i've been sexually abused before, being trapped like that was very triggering. However, I dont want my state to be seen as a reason for cheating or something.

Comment: Well, he thought you were cheating and hiding evidence, and when he tried to get a hold of it you suddenly ran to get rid of said evidence. I can understand why he would follow you and try to stop you under these assumptions, so I think it would be best to talk things out instead of assuming evil intentions from his side. In the best case, this is just one big misunderstanding that can be sorted out. Either way, it doesn't seem to fit the Q&A style of this page, as there is no concrete question we could answer here.

Comment: I wasnt planning on suing him or anything. Just worried that he would try to justify his actions in some way hat would cause me to look bad. I admit that when I left the first exam I was really hoping to get the same questions as I had looked them over, but there was no way of knowing for sure that I would, and my main motivation for memorizing stuff from the exam was to figure out if they did in fact recycle questions and possibly use that to my advantage next time. However, I did not do anything against the honour code on cheating.

Comment: Does your school allow you to bring a lawyer or other counsel to the hearing? If so, I strongly suggest you do so -- even assuming everything you say is accurate, there are enough pieces that do not add up that simply explaining the above may not be sufficient; counsel can advise on the best way to proceed.

Comment: I'm going with my counsellor. She was called when I had a panic attack after what happened with the male proctor and she helped me set up my counselling and doctors appointments and get back on sleeping and depression pills. The proctors actions have really opened up old scars. I don't know of any lawyers to call on such short notice, the meeting is tomorrow. I have booked a meeting with the ombudsman for after the deans meeting if it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but it looks like it will be impossible to prove your innocence under these conditions.  You refused to follow the instructions of the proctor because you "didn't feel comfortable with handing him [your] papers" (which is not a sufficient explanation), and later failed to control your emotions and ran into the washroom as if you were trying to get rid of some evidence.

Comment: He went in there with me though, so he watched me the whole time till someone else showed up.

Comment: Also he was the one that initially told me to take them myself, if he had taken them when he first asked me to go with him, I wouldnt have them on me in the first place. I should add that I write my exams in an exam centre due to having an anxiet disorder, I dont do well with sudden change like that. I panicked which is why I was hesistant